# $.post jQuery work only when alert inside post function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My button is :

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-primary btn-block"
          id="submit">Login</button>
```

And my form is :

```
<form action="b.php" method="post" id="formID" onsubmit="return post();">
```

And my JS function is :

```
function post()
{   
  var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
  var cs = $('#cs').val();
  $.post('a.php',{postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs});
  alert("Post Function work");  
}
```

My problem is: when I remove the `alert` from the `post()` function, it doesn't post to `a.php`, and when I use `return false` inside the `post()` function, the function works on `a.php`  but the page freezes and I can't get data from `b.php`!

Comment: is your `a.php` return some value on success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want the asynchronous `$.post` to complete before submitting the form, you need to:

- Prevent the submit from executing immediately, by returning false in your `post` function
- Add a success callback to your `$.post` call, in which you manually submit the form. Be sure to *not* trigger the submit via jQuery (using `.trigger('submit')` or `.submit()` on the jQuery object). This will cause an infinite loop, as it will trigger the `post` function again. Instead, use `get(0)` to get the raw DOM element and use that to submit the form, as seen below.

Try this:

```
function post() {
    var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
    var cs = $('#cs').val();
    $.post('a.php',{postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs}, function() {
        //Manually submit form
        $('#formID').get(0).submit()
    });
    return false;
}
```

For more information about adding callbacks for `$.post`, see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: corinnaerin how can i add success callback to manually submit ?

Comment: corinnaerin if you can give me an example :) thank you

Comment: corinnaerin i tried your code but the default action in b.php doesnt work :(

Comment: What exactly is happening then?  ("doesn't work" is not descriptive enough). Is the page not submitting? Are there any errors in your console? Is it possible that `a.php` is not executing successfully (in which case the success callback would not be triggered)?

Comment: sorry corinnaerin the page is not submitting :(

Comment: Could you possibly include a jsfiddle of your current code? It's difficult to debug without actual code. Alternatively, try using the javascript debugger to figure out what's happening, or put console.log statements. You can also use the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools to see if your ajax request is being completed successfully. I would guess that the success callback isn't being called for some reason.

Comment: I've got this error in console.log ==> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Ah, ok. That has nothing to do with the callback logic. It's a problem with the actual AJAX call. Generally, you can't use AJAX to call an endpoint that has a different domain, unless the server was configured to allow it - in this case the server has the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, so you're being blocked. Try googling that error message. Here's a article I found about it, I just skimmed it but it seems to be on point: https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/

Comment: Thank you corinnaerin :)

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the alert, the ajax will be fired off asyncronously and then your function will immediately return nothing back to the `onsubmit` event, which will cause the form to submit and a page change, before the ajax even completes.

Since you're returning the value to the onsubmit event, you can simply add a `return false` to your function. This will prevent the default action (submit) and stop propagation.

```
function post() {
    ...
    ...
    return false
}
```

Edit:

If you need the ajax to complete before allowing the form to submit then you should return false as above, but add a success handler to the ajax to manually submit the form.

```
function post()
{   
  var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
  var cs = $('#cs').val();
  $.post('a.php',{postcvs:cvs,postch1:cs}, function(){
      $('#formID')[0].submit();
  });
}
```

Comment: MrCode thank you for your answer but i want the default action work too

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit is cancelable event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)
if you "post" function return false, submit process cancelled.